# jquery auto filter cannot search information next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, pagination, autofilter

I want to add a text search box on my page. As I type in the box, it will show the search results on web page.

For example, I type "Ca", and the result shows "Cake", "California".... and I type "Cal", "Cake" will be filtered out.

I use jquery to do it. But right now I can only filter the result on single page.

For example, on the second page, it doesn't have "California", but it's on 1st page. I type "C", 0 result...

How I can do it? I use django framework. It's paginated in django.

Here is my code:

```
   $('#id').keyup(function(){ 

     var term = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

     $('.image-list>li').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).data("data-zb-name").toLowerCase();

        (text.indexOf(term) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
      });

    });
```

Comment: We're going to need more than this to be able to help you. Please provide information on how you present the options? An array? Database? And then also some code...

Comment: my code is very simple. I append it on my questions above.